# How to describe someone who likes to play word games *dissect every word you say - literally and/or non-literally*

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Sometimes we use certain words out of habit and not really intend to mean what it intends to mean. We may encounter people who will try to *play with your choice of words* either for fun with no ill intent, or they intentionally use it to annoy you.

I can't think of any good examples right off the bat, below are what I can manage so far at the moment and I hope it illustrates what I meant.

**Random Examples:**

> I am trying to .....

The person will say: Do not say *try*, say *you will*

> I feel that .....

The person will say: *You feel but you don't think?*

> I am medium (referring to clothes size)

The person will ask: *Where is large and small?*

Is there a term/description for this person's act? or is there a term/description for such individual?

For instance, if we call someone a *grammar nazi* we know the person is very particular with grammar. I'm wondering if there is a term/word/description that specifically mean someone who likes to *play* with words.

Answer (score 1):

a **pedant**:

a person who makes an excessive or inappropriate display of learning.
a person who overemphasizes rules or minor details.
a person who adheres rigidly to book knowledge without regard to common sense.

[from the dictionary](https://dictionary.com)

Comment: Thanks @Ricky. I've updated my question to provide more information on the word I have in mind.

Comment: A vocabulary nerd?